# awk: Shell variable not showing up when getting string from a file

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, awk

I have a file location_data.py, which contains a string variable

```
loc = "somewhere-$xyz"
```

In my shell, I have a variable name 'xyz' which has a value of 1.
When I do:

```
>loc=$(awk '/loc/{print $3}' location_data.py)
```

I get

> "somewhere-${xyz}"

instead, I want

> "somewhere-1"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass shell variable to `awk` by passing it to an `awk` variable then search inside `/.../` will also not work.

use like:

```
locNew=$(awk -v locVar="$loc" '$0 ~ locVar{print $3}' location_data.py)
```

***OR***

```
locNew=$(awk -v locVar="$loc" 'index($0,locVar){print $3}' location_data.py)
```

Also try to create a new shell variable(as a Good programming practice), in case you want to refer them in later on.